# Change Yahoo Blueprint application look&feel

Tags: mobile-website, look-and-feel

Is it possible to modify the "bluish style" of a mobile application developed with [Yahoo Blueprint](http://mobile.yahoo.com/developers) ?

I would like to use at least my own colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can unofficially change the page theme to one of many predefined themes.  For instance:

```
<page style="collection" theme="black">
```

See the Blueprint developer forums for more info: http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=5023